# kwargs and function signature

Tags: python, ide

Is there a way to provide signature reference(for example, for IDE) for function with **kwargs?

for example:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
  # call some third-party library with kwargs signature
```

I want to provide the autocomplete for most recent IDEs

So, how do I describe signature in Python

Comment: I don't think there's any _easy_ way to do this other than being explicit about the signature and avoiding `**kwargs`.  It also depends a bit on how the IDE is picking up the function signature -- Is it parsing the AST, or is it actually importing the module?

Comment: I think the same way) But I guess there is should be a way to describe this. Maybe some form of comments

Comment: If you're looking for magic comments, that depends entirely on the IDE.  python3.x adds function annotations which some IDEs might be able to introspect, but again, that's not going to help you describe the kwargs any easier than just writing them out...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite what you want but it might... `help`.

```
from other_package import my_function


def wrapped_help_text(wrapped_func):
    """Decorator to pass through the documentation from a wrapped function.
    """
    def decorator(wrapper_func):
        """The decorator.

        Parameters
        ----------
        wrapped_func : callable
            The wrapped function.

        """
        wrapper_func.__doc__ = ('This method wraps the following method:\n\n' +
                                pydoc.text.document(wrapped_func))
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator


@wrapped_help_text(my_function)
def wrapper(**kwargs):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    **kwargs
        See other_package.my_function()

    """
    my_function(**kwargs)
```

With this you can now call the built-in `help` function to see the docstring for the wrapped function.

Comment: This approach also has an advantage: python docstring support is built in to many if not most python-compatible IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.3, you cann assign any custom signature to `function.__signature__`. This is *runtime behaviour* though. So if the IDE just looks at the AST, this won't work. But anything actually importing the module, like executing `help()` in the Python REPL or running `pydoc` on the module will work.

The following example simply retrieves the signature from the "wrapped" function and assigns it to the "wrapping" function.

In addition to simply copying the signature, you can craft your own `signature.Signature` objects or modify the signature before assigning it if needed.

```
import inspect

def wrapped(foo: str, a: int = 10) -> bool:
    return True


def wrapping(*args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

wrapping.__signature__ = inspect.signature(wrapped)
```